# Access denied for user 'administrator'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: odbc, asterisk

I've a user account setup `asteriskpbx@localhost`. From this account I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
echo "select 1" | isql -v asterisk-connector
```

However, I get this error :

```
[S1000][unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for user 'administrator'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Why does it show **Access denied for user 'administrator'@'localhost'** when I'm running this command from **asteriskpbx@localhost** ?

**Note:** I've database permissions setup for asteriskpbx user account, which I don't want to compromise on.

Comment: More information is required to answer this question.  What other users do you have setup.  What operating system.

Comment: The general answer is that `isql` isn't picking up the permissions you want it to; it seems to be running as Administrator, rather than as the asteriskpbx user. The question to answer is: why should that be happening? Is `isql` set to run as administrator, for example?

Comment: @Ramhound Currently, I'm the only user, but in future there will be users who will be accessing asterisk server through this account. I'm using centos.

Comment: @AaronMiller That could be the reason. I'll check the ownership of isql.

Comment: @FireAndIce - You have more then a singel user otherwise it wouldn't be trying to use the `administrator` user to run the command.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I've more than a single user on my system, root, adminstrator and asteriskpbx. But, I'm executing the command as asteriskpbx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen from the error, in your /etc/odbc.ini in asterisk-connector you have

> UID             = administrator # where asteriskpbx should be

This is the only reason why isql would try to connect as administrator that I can think of.

If this connects (delete -h [host-ip] if you ran it on localhost):

> mysql -h [host-ip] - u asteriskpbx --password=[asteriskpbx-password]

Than after change of odbc.ini you shouldn't have any problems

Hope it helps.

Mirko

Comment: I finally got it running by this command, `echo "select 1" | isql -v asterisk-connector UID PWD`

Answer (score 1):

I've just made changes in `/etc/odbc.ini`.

For MySQL Driver Connect:

Changed: UserName to UID and it works.

Below is the configuration details:

```
[MYSQL]
Description = MySQL connection
Driver = MySQL
Database = <Database Name>
Server = <Host Name>
UID = <Your-DB Username>
Password = <Your-password>
Port = 3306
```